# jQuery hover function - what am I missing?

Tags: jquery, html, hover, jquery-animate

I'm simply trying to animate some div's I have in my HTML code. I just took a summer course and now that it's over I want to keep coding and learning more, so I'm just messing around, but coming up short.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '68px',opacity: '0.3'},'650'),
            function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '45px',opacity: '1.0'},'650');
        };
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell everything is set up fine, and the reason I went with hover is because 'mouseenter/leave' don't work in chrome (for whatever reason). I looked through a bunch of similar questions but couldn't find what I've been looking for.

Comment: Can you setup an example at jsFiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b8up9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bracing is messed up.  I think it should be this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '68px',opacity: '0.3'},'650');
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '45px',opacity: '1.0'},'650');
    });
});
```

FYI, if you look in your browser's error console or the debug console, it should show you syntax errors like this.

And, you probably want to add `.stop(true, true)` so animations don't pile up if you move the mouse quickly in and out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({height: '68px',opacity: '0.3'},'650');
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({height: '45px',opacity: '1.0'},'650');
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tZEWy/

Comment: Yes, it should work.....and also.....give id to your div (id='abc') and use $('#abc') instead of $('div')

Comment: Yes, your code works, but when I save and run from notepad++ it still does not animate.

Comment: @JAPytlak - Then, apparently there is something wrong with how you are putting it into another page.  The code is correct and runs in this jsFiddle.  Do you have jQuery loaded in this other page?  Can you provide a link to this other page?  Without showing us the actual page you're running it in, all we can do is guess what might be wrong.

Comment: @JAPytlak: That sounds like its probably a different question then, possibly more about notepad++ than javascript (I don't use it so no idea what your problem might be).

Comment: http://moxie.cs.oswego.edu/~jpytlak/projects/

is the site, maybe I am missing something super simple?

Comment: @jfriend00: I assumed from the fact it can apparently run things from there that it might invoke browsers in some special way that prevents scripts running or something...

Comment: @JAPytlak - you have to include the jQuery library in your project.  Put this in your HTML file before your jproject.js file: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: It is as jfriend00 guessed that you aren't including jquery. Add this line to your header: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (from https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide )

Comment: (or you may want a different version, that was just the one that was easiest to copy and paste)

Comment: well i'll be dipped! thanks - how dumb of me, but then again, we did most of our learning at codeacademy.com so I don't recall this aspect at all (if it was even part of it). thanks again :)

Comment: @JAPytlak - please immediately learn how to look at your browser's error console or debugger console.  Both would have shown you this error immediately without needing to ask for help.

Comment: gotcha, gotcha. I do appreciate the help, I just started looking at html/css/javascript/jquery 6 weeks ago and I really want to do as much as I can on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to close the first function. Here try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({height: '68px',opacity: '0.3'},'650');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({height: '45px',opacity: '1.0'},'650');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: There's still an extra semicolon after the second function's closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's hover function is just a mixture of 2 functions!

It is a mixture of `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` and they are in its parameters.

So the `.hover` is this `.hover(.mouseenter, .mouseleave)`.

So then you have to do it like this:

```
$('div').hover(function(){

    $(this).animate({height: '68px',opacity: '0.3'},'650');

} /*mouseenter */, function(){

    $(this).animate({height: '45px',opacity: '1.0'},'650');

} /*mouseleave*/);
```